# inserting div and it's contents within another div using jQuery chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Scenario:**

So, I have the below:

```
$('.interchangablediv').css( 'background-image' , 'url(images/instance1.png)' );
```

I want to have a few sets of unique div content that I would like to toggle at the same time as the above jQuery chaining. *ie.* below mark-up

```
<div class="htmlset1">
Blah, Blah, Blah, Heyyy
</div>
```

**Question:**

I simply would like to invoke the '`htmlset1`' div and it's contents inside the '`interchangablediv`' above (and it's styles) when my line of jQuery at the top of this question is ran.

Comment: so you want to `append` `htmlset1` to '.interchangablediv' and set the background of `.interchangablediv` at the same time?

Comment: Yeahhh, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It looks like from your question `htmlset1`  is already in the DOM so that concern has to be addressed. Do you want to clone that `htmlset1` element remove it and append it. or will `htmlset1` be dynamically created with javascript (like make `var html = "<div class = 'htmlset1'>"`) and then append it to` '.interchangablediv'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the (outer) html of `htmlset1` by:
`$('<div>').append($('.htmlset1').clone()).html()`

This creates a `div`, appends a clone of `htmlset1` then gets the `div`'s html.

From there, you can just chain onto your current code.  So the whole thing would be the following:
`$('.interchangablediv').css( 'background-image' , 'url(images/instance1.png)' ).html( $('<div>').append($('.htmlset1').clone()).html() );`

Answer (score 0):

I don't truly understand. Did you mean?:

```
var inter = document.getElementById("interchangablediv");
var divhtmlset = document.getElementById("htmlset1");
inter.appendChild(divhtmlset);
```